# Font Scaling in Windows 8 vs Font Scaling in Windows 7 (under high DPI - 144)

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8, windows-7, dpi

Ok, I am aware of developing high dpi applications in WinForms and WPF, but while testing some features in Windows8, I stumbled upon something weird.

I have a *WinForms* application with **AutoScalingMode** set to **DPI**. The form has a bunch of labels. All the labels' font units are measured in points *but one (the red label which reads "This text block is special. Its size is 18px"), as its size is set to 18px and not pt*.

I ran the application in Windows 7 as well as Windows 8. 
**Windows 7 does not auto scale** this (the red one) label as expected but **Windows 8 auto scales the same label**!

What could be the issues? Is there a documented statement from Microsoft stating that Auto Scaling set to None won't work in Windows 8?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I guess I found the reason. I will have to disable the DWM settings to "Disable display scaling on high DPi settings". If I do so, then it is not scaling the text in Windows 8.

But I did not have to do this in Windows 7 and still it works fine! Wondering why..!

Comment: There are a whole host of DPI/font scaling related changes in Win8 and Win8.1. This is just a consequence of those changes.